# Can I mix Objective-C and C++ in a single application in Xcode?

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode

I have some legacy code to reuse written in c++ with opengl but most of the examples online are written in objective c... so porting my code would be probably easier in a mixed env.

I would prefer to avoid a "library" solution with separated .so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. Just add your c++ code in a file called *.cpp

You can even mix C++ and objective-c code in the same file, but make sure the file is named *.mm (instead of *.m). That's a gotacha that a lot of people fall far.

Considering you want to use some legacy C++ code, this is probably exactly what you are looking for: [Sample code from Apple for Cocoa With Carbon or CPP](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/Cocoa_With_Carbon_or_CPP/Introduction/Intro.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use both in a single project. If memory serves, the extension for "Objective-C++" files is `.mm`.